# How do you print current pensize in Python using Turtle module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I have written a paint program in Python, it works well but for extra credit I need to be able to print the current pensize of the turtle.

I tried using a `while` loop which does not work:

```
while True:
    print loki.pensize()
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Does anything error or print with that statement?

Comment: yes i get this errot : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items' on line 89 in main.py

Comment: Could you show us that line and the ones around it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can retrieve the current pensize using the `turtle.pensize()` method, e.g.:

```
>>> turtle.pensize()
1
```

For more help please contact the docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.pensize

Answer (score 0):

You can print the pensize with this code.

```
import turtle 

painter = turtle.Turtle()
painter.pensize(10) #set pen size
print painter.pensize()
```

You can also get a full list of the pen attributes with `print painter.pen().items()`

Comment: It won't do what you say. I see no `print` statement, and also you set the pensize instead of getting it.

Comment: Left a line off. Let me fix that. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, I am trying to print the pensize in the program, would it help if I showed my code?

Comment: Yes but if this is the code you are looking for then please accept the answer